# 4 black wires for light switch

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to replace my master closet light switch with a single pole dimmer switch but the wiring doesn't seem to correspond. The old switch has 2 black wires back stabbed, 1 black wire that's tapped on the bottom screw (looks like 2 black wires coming off the switch), and the ground screwed on the top. Im replacing it with the Lutron Maestro which has 2 black wires, 1 green+1ground. 
[image]
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pig tail the 3 blacks and run it to 1 side of the switch and the other black goes to the other side then put your ground on the yoke ground screw and you will be good to go.

Comment: Okay, so cut the black wire that's tapped into 2 wires and pigtail them with the bottom black back stabbed wire?

Comment: you may not have to cut the wire there is a small hole next to the wire a small screwdriver or piece of 14 Awg solid wire will usually release the wires in a back stab.

Comment: No, I mean the tapped black wire that's screwed at the bottom of the pic. Its one wire that's stripped in the middle (not sure if you can see that) and screwed on. I'm wondering if I should cut it where it's stripped and pigtail it with the back stabbed wire.

Comment: It may be better to leave the wire long and just make sure the tape is in good shape. Once the wires get cut short it makes it difficult to get them in the box. I have seen pigtails that the original wires were not long enough to exit the box (wire length code is 6" from the back of the box).